# How to parse json present in an xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, json

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://s.com/webservices/">{
  "Status": "0",
  "UserID": "2",
  "SessionTimeOut": "10",
  "TestList": [
    {
      "PlantCode": "01",
      "PlantName": "Master",
      "PlantAddr": "Master",
      "PlantID": "1"
    },
    {
      "PlantCode": "02",
      "PlantName": "Plant1",
      "PlantAddr": "Plant1",
      "PlantID": "2"
    }
  ]
}</string>
```

I have a json inside an xml response. I can parse json however how do i retrieve it from the response.

EDIT: Worked when i did the following:

```
   var xml = response;
        var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
                $jqXml = $(xmlDoc),
                $json = $jqXml.find('string');
        var jsonRaw = $.parseJSON($json.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://s.com/webservices/">{"Status": "0"}</string>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$jqXml = $(xmlDoc);
$json = $jqXml.find('string');
var jsonRaw = $.parseJSON($json.text());
```

Here's a JSFiddle example with your full XML string:

https://jsfiddle.net/kzukj66e/

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the response, it is best to send the response as pure Json rather than enclosing it in xml string.

Otherwise you can also try sending xml string and parse xml using built in functions.

**highly un-recommended** : If due to some strange constraints you are unable to send pure json or pure xml, a solution would be to use regular expressions to separate the json from xml . Following javascript regex can help separate json from xml (can be improved)

```
json = original.replace(/^.*?(\{.*?)\<.*$/s,'$1')
```

Comment: Hi this is being sent by our client who isn't ready to change the format :(

Comment: var p="/^.*?(\{.*?)\<.*$/s,'$1'/";
         var jsona = (response+"").replace(p);
         
         alert(jsona);
i tried this get the output [object XMLDocument]

Comment: instead of alert, use console.log to get a clear picture in browser console. Also it seems that the response is an object which first needs to be converted to a string.